# Microsoft Edge propagates autocomplete dropdown to next route / page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, microsoft-edge, react-router-dom

I have the folloing very simple dummy `ReactJS` project:

`Source Code` with Preview:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8rgbu7

where there are two components:

**components/Address.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Address extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: '',
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/email');
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let value = target.value;
    let name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{padding:'10px'}}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h4>What is your street address? Example: 001 foo</h4>
          <span>these are some</span><br />
          <span>dummy lines</span><br />
          <span>on purpose</span><br /><br />
          <input type="text" name="address" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.address} />
          <button type="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Address;
```

**components/Email.js**

```
import React from 'react';

class Email extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/');
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let value = target.value;
    let name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{padding:'10px'}}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <h4>What is your email address?</h4>
          <input type="text" name="email" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.email} />
          <button type="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Email;
```

**My problem is:** On `Microsoft Edge` browser (the rest of the browsers are fine), when jumping to the next route (on this case: `Email.js`), the autocomplete dropdown from the previous route (on this case: `Address.js`) is still there.

Any idea on how to fix this? (remember this issue is only on `Microsoft Edge`)

Here you have a `screencast` you can easily see:

[image]

Try it with `Microsoft Edge`: https://react-8rgbu7.stackblitz.io

As you may notice, the isse is `NOT` that the autocomplete dropdown from the input on the first page is applied to the input on the second page, `BUT` the autocomplete dropdown from the input on the first page gets stuck on the browser even when the first page (a `React` component) gets unmounted.

Here you can play around:

(preview with `Microsoft Edge`): https://react-8rgbu7.stackblitz.io

(`source code`): https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8rgbu7

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the handleSubmit function, try to use `window.location.href="/email";` to redirect to another page:

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.props.history.push('/email');
    window.location.href="/email";
  };
```

**Edit**:

There has another option, you could disable the Edge browser Autofill function:

[image]

Then, if you want to achieve the autocomplete function, you could use the Autocomplete component(such as [Material-UI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/), [React Autocomplete](https://github.com/reactjs/react-autocomplete)).

**Edit**

There have another method might be help you: In the Address.js file, remove **the `<form>` tag's onSubmit** event and change the **`Submit`** button to general button. Then, use the button click event to handle the submit function.

After modified, the Address.js file as below:

```
import React from 'react';

class Address extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      address: '',
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/email');
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    let value = target.value;
    let name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{padding:'10px'}}>
        <form>
          <h4>What is your street address? Example: 001 foo</h4>
          <span>these are some</span><br />
          <span>dummy lines</span><br />
          <span>on purpose</span><br /><br />
          <input type="text" name="address" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.address} />
          <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Next</button>
        </form> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Address;
```

The local side test results as below:

[image]

Comment: unfortunatelly that's not an option because we are trying to take advantage of the history API on this Single Page Application (SPA). If we assign a new value to `window.location.href` then this app is not a SPA anymore.

Comment: @Viewsonic, please check my Edit, and try to disable the Edge browser autofill function.

Comment: thank you @zhi for your advice, but Unfortunatelly modifying Edge settings is not an option for us either, since we cannot rely on our users to do that.

Comment: Try to use the button click event to submit the form, please refer to my edit.

Comment: could you please, provide a forked stackblitz? thanks!

Comment: @Viewsonic, Based on your [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8rgbu7), in the Address.js file, remove the <form> tag's onSubmit event. and change the submit button (Next button) code as below: `<button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Next</button>`

Comment: but I need the autocomplete feature to be working properly, if I remove the <form> tag then that won't work any more

Comment: @Viewsonic, Just remove **the <form> tag's onSubmit event**, instead of the <form> tag. the screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8oGX.png). Besides, the local test result as below: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltpdl.gif).

Comment: could you please, provide the corresponding stackblitz based on the one I provided? thanks!

Comment: @Viewsonic, you could check this sample: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sn5bsb](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sn5bsb)

Comment: hi @Zhi there are two issues with that approach: 1- on the address step, when clicking next, whatever brand new introduced value is not remembered for the future. 2- on the address step, when hitting Enter, it reloads the page. Is it possible to solve these issues? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue recently, it is because you are using

```
<button type="submit">
```

instead of

```
<input type="submit">
```

Indeed, I know that the preferable way is using `<button>` but not sure why this happen only on old edge version.

You can check the forked stackblitz for the working solution in
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yshvrb.

[image]